# How to change an existing alias in Thingsboard

Tags: thingsboard

I was wondering if there is a way to change an entity alias. I can only add new aliases when I am setting a new data source to any chart. However, I can't find those aliases to change them.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: 
Just right-click on the dashboard background - there I found the contex-menu "entity aliases".